# Kubernetes service running fine but unable to access from outside

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

Hi I am trying to do communication between a mongo database and nodejs application using kubernetes. everything is running fine . but I ma unable to access my api from outside environment. I am also not able to telnet the port.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node
  labels:
    app: node
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      nodePort: 30005
  externalIPs:
    - 34.73.154.127 
  # # Replace with the IP of your minikube node / master node
  # selector:
  #   app: node 
  #   tier: backend
```

this is my service yaml file

when i am checking the status of port using command
`sudo lsof -i:30005`
I am able to see the results as below

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
kube-prox 2925 root    8u  IPv6  32281      0t0  TCP *:30005 (LISTEN)
```

Now i should be able to telnet the port with ip like
`telnet 34.73.154.127 30005`  but I am getting result as below.

```
Trying 34.73.154.127...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

If any of my friend is going to suggest that port is not open then please note that i have open all the port range from anywhere.

One more thing I want to let you know that I deployed a sample node application natively using npm on port 30006 and i am able to telnet on this port. So conclusion is that all the port range is open and working.

This is the describe command result of service
`kubectl describe service/node`
result:

```
Name:                     node
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=node
                          tier=backend
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"node","tier":"backend"},"name":"node","namespace":"defau...
Selector:                 <none>
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.102.42.145
External IPs:             34.73.154.127
Port:                     <unset>  3000/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30005/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Please let me know what is wrong with me ..

```
ENVIRONMENT: 
cloud :google cloud platform
container :using docker and kubernetes
ubuntu 16.04 LTS
kubernetes 1.13.0
```

Comment: Did you check the firewall rules?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts I have mentioned that i have open all the port to access from anywhere.

Comment: Did you try to test the application in the pod with port 3000? Is it running?

Comment: did you exposed the ports inside the container? [bind](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)

Comment: @Luke yes I have exposed that

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was doing a silly mistake .
Just uncommented this in my service yaml file and it started working

```
# # Replace with the IP of your minikube node / master node
  # selector:
  #   app: node 
  #   tier: backend
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your service from the outside you need to expose this service as a LoadBalancer type such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node
  labels:
    app: node
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      nodePort: 30005
```

Google Cloud Platform will provision you an IP Address that is publicly routable and will open the firewall *for* you.

Comment: result of `kubectl describe service/node` after update https://pastebin.com/321YBZq4